# Harddrive 9 in 1 capacity? What does that mean?

Tags: hard-drive, terminology

I have to define some stuff for my operating systems class based on a computer ad, and it says the hard disk capacity is "9-in-1." What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the capacity of the drive, but rather it has to do with other features that the [enclosure supports](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000M0A2M4).

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's referring to a memory card/"media" reader that can accept many different kinds of memory card form factors, such as:

- SecureDigital (SD) cards, including Mini and Micro variants
- Olympus/Fujifilm xD cards
- SmartMedia cards
- Sony Memory Stick, including PRO and or M2 variants

These media readers often sport USB connectors as well so they can accept a USB external hard drive as well.